# Filter different divs with list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, filter

I have some divs with different content in it. On the left side i have got a list with differenct categories. With a click on a categorie I want to load the div of this category.
At the beginning I want to have the main category loaded. So there is no option to show all elements.

```js
var $eBayElements = $('.row > div.col-lg-9');
$('.filter_link').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var filterVal = $(this).data('filter');
    
  $eBayElements.hide().filter(filterVal).show();
});;
```

```html
<section class="area1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="section-title text-center pb-10">
          <h3 class="title">Aktuelle Angebote</h3>
          <p class="text">Hier werden Dir einige Angebote angezeigt. Schau Dich einfach um!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="offer-menu text-center mt-50">
          <ul>
            <li class="filter_link" data-filter=".main" class="active">Alles</li>
            <li class="filter_link" data-filter=".handys">Handys</li>
            <li class="filter_link" data-filter=".spiele">Videospiele</li>
            <li class="filter_link" data-filter=".books">Bücher</li>
            <li class="filter_link" data-filter=".toys">Spielzeug</li>
            <li class="filter_link" data-filter=".cams">Kameras</li>
            <li class="filter_link" data-filter=".auktionen">Auktionen</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 main">
        <div>...</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 handys">
        <div>...</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 spiele">
        <div>...</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 books">
        <div>...</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 toys">
        <div>...</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 cams">
        <div>...</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 auktionen">
        <div>...</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Unfortunately it does not work porperly. It would be very nice if anyoine could help me with that. Thank you very much!

Comment: ` data-filter=".all"` these already have `.` in the data-filter. You are adding one in the `filter()` function as well.

Comment: Also the selector for `$shopElements` needs to select the `div` within the `.row`, not the `ul`: `$('.row > div.col-lg-9')`

Comment: Tank you very much! Now it is working a bit better than before. I specified my post because there was a little missunderstanding. I do not want to have an option to show all elements. I always want to show one element at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".filter_link").click(function(e){
  $('.row > div.col-lg-9').hide()
  $($(this).data("filter")).show()
});
```

```css
.handys, .spiele, .books, .toys, .cams, .auktionen{
 display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="area1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="section-title text-center pb-10">
                    <h3 class="title">Aktuelle Angebote</h3>
                    <p class="text">Hier werden Dir einige Angebote angezeigt. Schau Dich einfach um!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                <div class="offer-menu text-center mt-50">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="filter_link" data-filter=".all" class="active">Alles</li>
                        <li class="filter_link" data-filter=".handys">Handys</li>
                        <li class="filter_link" data-filter=".spiele">Videospiele</li>
                        <li class="filter_link" data-filter=".books">Bücher</li>
                        <li class="filter_link" data-filter=".toys">Spielzeug</li>
                        <li class="filter_link" data-filter=".cams">Kameras</li>
                        <li class="filter_link" data-filter=".auktionen">Auktionen</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 all">
                <div>All</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 handys">
                <div>Handy</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 spiele">
                <div>Sp</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 books">
                <div>Bool</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 toys">
                <div>toys</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 cams">
                <div>cams</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 auktionen">
                <div>.aut</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need all categories into one div. also you used data attribute with classname.

in my example i've called like you "all"

```
        <div class="col-lg-9">
         <div class="all">
          <div class="handys">
            <div>handys</div>
            <div>handys 2</div>
            <div>handys 3</div>
          </div>
          <div class="spiele">
            <div>spiele</div>
            <div>spiele 2</div>
            <div>spiele 3</div>
          </div> ....
        </div>
       </div>
```

script

```
var $shopElements = $('.offer-menu ul');
  $('.filter_link').click(function(e) {
    var filterVal = $(this).data('filter');
    $(".all > div").show();
    if(filterVal == "all") return;
    $(".all  > div:not(." + filterVal + ")").hide();
  });
```

working example on jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wjs640kt/

or same code here at **Run code snippet**:

```js
 var $shopElements = $('.offer-menu ul');
      $('.filter_link').click(function(e) {
        var filterVal = $(this).data('filter');
        $(".all > div").show();
        if(filterVal == "all") return;
        $(".all  > div:not(." + filterVal + ")").hide();
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="section-title text-center pb-10">
        <h3 class="title">Aktuelle Angebote</h3>
        <p class="text">Hier werden Dir einige Angebote angezeigt. Schau Dich einfach um!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <div class="offer-menu text-center mt-50">
        <ul>
          <li class="filter_link" data-filter="all" class="active">Alles</li>
          <li class="filter_link" data-filter="handys">Handys</li>
          <li class="filter_link" data-filter="spiele">Videospiele</li>
          <li class="filter_link" data-filter="books">Bücher</li>
          <li class="filter_link" data-filter="toys">Spielzeug</li>
          <li class="filter_link" data-filter="cams">Kameras</li>
          <li class="filter_link" data-filter="auktionen">Auktionen</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
      <div class="all">
        <div class="handys">
          <div>handys</div>
          <div>handys 2</div>
          <div>handys 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="spiele">
          <div>spiele</div>
          <div>spiele 2</div>
          <div>spiele 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="books">
          <div>books</div>
          <div>books 2</div>
          <div>books 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="toys">
          <div>toys</div>
          <div>toys 2</div>
          <div>toys 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cams">
          <div>cams</div>
          <div>cams 2</div>
          <div>cams 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="auktionen">
          <div>auktionen</div>
          <div>auktionen 2</div>
          <div>auktionen 3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```